# ReadOnly property is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(currRow[0].cells[j]).find("*").attr("readonly", "readonly");
```

I want to make the selected cell as readonly but it is not working.
below is the selected row.

```
<a title="" data-original-title="" class="btn btn-default day-popover-button fixed-btn-size" href="javascript:;"><span class="b-questions set-zero">0</span><span class="project-unit set-q">SC</span><input class="b-questions-hidden d-item set-zero" id="id_form-0-tuesdayQ" name="form-0-tuesdayQ" value="0.0" type="hidden">
 <span class="b-hours Tue-t set-zero">0</span>H
<input class="b-hours-hidden d-item set-zero" id="id_form-0-tuesdayH" name="form-0-tuesdayH" value="0" type="hidden"></a>
```

But if i am disabling the selected row fields, it is working below is the code

```
$(currRow[0].cells[j]).find("*").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

But in above case my data requirement validation is failing, which is in backend.
I don't want to make any change in backeend. 
If anyone have solution for javascript, please let me know.

Comment: yeah i tried that also with prop keyword

Comment: You don't show any elements that `readonly` can apply to. It doesn't apply to hidden inputs or links, because neither can be edited by the user anyway.

Comment: even at the place of "*" i kept "input " also but it didn't work

Comment: $(currRow[0].cells[j]).find("input").prop("readonly", true);

Comment: @vivek pradhan create a fiddle, it will be easy to assist you.

Comment: I am trying but my css is not working here

Comment: try it like ... $(currRow[0].cells[j]).find("input").prop("disabled", true);

Comment: @AmitChauhan this way also the same  problem. we can edit the value.